# How to get the full code function body of a function node from the Typescript Compiler?

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript-compiler-api

I'm relatively new to doing stuff with the Typescript Compiler. I'm trying to write some code that:

Given a `.ts` file, it can extract all the functions from it. Specifically, I'm trying to achieve an array of objects of the type `{ funcName: string, funcBody: string }` where `funcName` is the name of the function, and `funcBody` is the overall code of the function (including the function declaration).

Currently, I have this simple piece of code

```
export async function extract(file: string) {
  const program = ts.createProgram([file], { allowJs: true });
  const sourceFile = program.getSourceFile(file);
  if (!sourceFile) return [];

  const output: any = [];

  ts.forEachChild(sourceFile, (node) => {
    if (ts.isFunctionDeclaration(node)) {
      const funcName = node.name ? node.name.text : "<anonymous>";
      const funcBody = node.body;
      console.log({ funcName, funcBody });
    }
  });
}
```

It is able to get the `funcName` just fine, but I am unable to figure out how to get the actual `funcBody`.

Comment: Use a printer and print the function declaration node, would be my first guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and funcBody is the overall code of the function (including the function declaration).

If you want to get the text of the **function declaration** without leading trivia (comments & whitespace), then you can do:

```
if (ts.isFunctionDeclaration(node)) {
  const funcName = node.name ? node.name.text : "<anonymous>";
  const funcDecl = node.getText(sourceFile);
  console.log({ funcName, funcDecl });
}
```

To get just the **function body** text, use `node.body.getText(sourceFile).slice(1, -1).trim()` (slice to remove the surrounding braces).

A good resource is: https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCgEpEBvAKESsQgQGc58A6XOAcwIFYiBucgXyA (It will tell you the result of `.getText()` in the rightmost column)

Comment: Thank you, this worked beautifully. I tried `getText` but I didn't pass in `sourceFile` to it. That seems to have made the difference.

Comment: The source file is where it gets the file text from. Providing it to `getText` is an optimization so it doesn't have to go all the way up the tree to get the source file in order to get the text. In the question code it should work since `node` is a descendant of `sourceFile`.